# Permanent Activity as "home"

Tags: android

Is there a way to keep an application's main activity always alive in the foreground? I mean, the Home key or the Back key disabled.

The application will be used by ordinary users and administrators. The idea is that only the administrator can, from an internal activity of the application, access the rest of the system.

I have read that there is no way to override Home key, so any confirmation/workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: The users don't want to be locked out of the rest of the system by rogue application, so the system rightly does not allow it. I think you'll have to build custom version of the system (all necessary components are freely available on http://android.git.kernel.org) where you replace the launcher with your application. After all, the device with such application would be special-purpose, so it's OK to need special-purpose system image.

Comment: Thanks! This is one of the firsts solutions that we had in mind, but for prototyping and first releases of our application it would be too expensive for our costumer or, even worse, for us. Thanks the non-dramatic recommendation about custom image! xD

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the easiest way would be to create a Home replacement.

Comment: This is another option, but as I said to @Jan Hudec, we want to test the application as a prototype with no "noise" in the classic application structure. So I wanted a simple way based on overriding standard behavior before making non-standard applications. Anyway, I will deal with the Home replacement in order to get used to this kind of apps. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Override the OnKeyDown of an Activity where you can capture all key events,check if home or back back pressed if that pressed return as true. it wont propagate event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example To prevent the back key in android

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (  Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) < 7 //Instead use android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
            && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // Take care of calling this method on earlier versions of
        // the platform where it doesn't exist.
        onBackPressed();
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  return;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have a similar method implemented but for Home key it is forbidden as long as I read in docs and forums. The system protects the Home key as a "pannic button" so you can't override its behavior. Maybe there are workarounds but I wanted to know if there is a 'official' way to do this. Thank you anyway.